# Unable to run the Google Cloud SDK CLI on Windows + Powershell 7 due to python issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Recently after having no problems for months I suddenly am unable to run the Google Cloud SDK CLI / gcloud commands in Windows Terminal / PowerShell 7 (7.3).

The error I am getting is:

```
>gcloud
C:\Users\admin10lap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in ''
```

This appears to happen both with and without the bundled python option on the Google Cloud SDK installer (as I've tried re-installing the Google Cloud SDK multiple times).

Strangely, I do not get this error when using PowerShell 5.x or CMD prompt and nthe gcp SDK CLI runs fine in those instances.

PowerShell 7 has become my daily driver due to the enhancements and customizations it offers when used in conjunction with Windows terminal, so I'm desperate to get it working again.

I'm a bit out of my depth on how to troubleshoot this specific issue, if anyone has any insight as to what might be at play causing PowerShell 7 to throw this python error I would greatly appreciate any feedback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon checking around, I found this [Github issue link](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18529) wherein a bug was already filed after gcloud stopped working after updating PowerShell to 7.3. An issue is filed for [Google Cloud](https://issuetracker.google.com/259295558) as well. You can keep track of both links for now.

As of the moment, there are some workarounds that we could perform:

- Set [`$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = "Legacy"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables?view=powershell-7.3#psnativecommandargumentpassing), more information on this link about [Preference Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3)
- Use PowerShell 7.2

Let me know if you have questions or clarifications.

Comment: Thanks Robert, you're a lifesaver! I will give the Preference Variable option a shot and otherwise go for 7.2. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Since the first answer was accepted there have been several updates to the tickets at [Google Cloud](https://issuetracker.google.com/259295558) and [Github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18529). The issue was fixed per the former in gcloud SDK version 413.0.0. If you are running a version older than that, you can perform the fix manually. First, use this command to get the location of gcloud.ps1:

`Get-Command gcloud | Select-Object Source`

Next, edit that file. Around or at line 109 will be this text:

`$run_args_array += $cloudsdk_python_args.split(' ')`

replace the line entirely with this:

`$run_args_array += $cloudsdk_python_args.split(' ', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)`

This is the fix from version 413.0.0, so gcloud will run after that. I recommend that the very first invocation after this point be `gcloud components update`.

(h/t to [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18529#issuecomment-1332310877) for the above steps)